# How can I make a more efficient Entity Framework LINQ call than a nested loop

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Is there a more efficent way to write this LINQ statement?

Feature uses the same model as Product (as they are almost identical).

```
var products = db.Products.Where(q => q.IsFeature == false).ToList();
        foreach (Product pr in products)
        {
            var features = db.Products.Where(q => q.ParentID == pr.ID).ToList();
            foreach(Product feature in features)
            {
                pr.Features.Add(feature);
            }
        }
```

And the model:

```
    public class Product
{
    //START
    public Product()
    {
        Features = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsFeature { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }// If IsFeature is true we need to know its parent

    //Nav Props
    public ICollection<Product> Features { get; set; }// Features can be represented with the same model as product as they are almost identical
}
```

This does what I need ie a List of Product (Products), each with its own List of Feature (Features) but are there more elegant/efficient alternatives?

Comment: If you have a foreign key set up you should be able to use `.Include(p => p.Features)` - did you try that? Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: @Default Its self referencing, ID -> ProductID is the relationship. I thought .Include couldn't be filtered, ill take a look thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a `join`:

```
var productFeatures = 
    db.Products.Where(q => !q.IsFeature)
    .Join(db.Products, p => p.ID, f => f.ParentId, (p, f) => new { product: p, features: f.ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

For each object in `db.Products.Where(q => !q.IsFeature)` this will find each of the `db.Products` that have a `ParentId` equal to its `ID` field.

The results will be projected into a `List()` of anonymous types with the fields `product (Product)` and `features (List<Product>)`

Comment: I think that `.Join()` outputs a flat list, since `f` in the 4th Join parameter is a single item, not an `IEnumerable<>`.  Doesn't this need modified to do a `.GroupBy(e => e.Product)` after the `.Join()`?

Comment: @paul I can't get this to work, there are syntax errors and I don't fully understand this particular LINQ syntax to be able to correct it. Back to linq pad for me.

Comment: @afrazier You'd use `GroupBy` if you wanted an aggregated column (sum, avg, min, max etc). In this case, `GroupBy` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

If this operation has a complexity which rises to the point where the generated Linq's SQL becomes a hindrance or this business logic is done in multiple places;  consider placing the logic in a stored procedure.

Once in the database simply map the results in EF which later can easily be consumed by the code. Hence the complexity is moved off of the client and directly on the database.

Steps (*Database First*)

1. Create Stored procedure.
2. Update the model from the database and choose the stored procedure.
3. Verify the resultant mappings in EF's `Model Browser`.
4. Consume the named stored procedure off of the data context.

---

I discuss the ins-and-outs of mapping stored procedures on my blog article [Entity Framework Stored Procedure Instructions](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1158).

Comment: Are you saying that my nested foreach loops are Ok and cant be improved except by moving to a SP?

Comment: @TinoMclaren, no I am not saying that your request cannot be improved on the client. This is just providing an alternative *if the query ultimately created* relies on bloated sql. I do recommend in this post, that when one is done to look at the resultant SQL which Linq will generate to determine if it is efficient. (One can do that in [LinqPad](http://linqpad.net) easily after working in the Linq).  Its simply an alternative.

Comment: @TinoMclaren I like Pauls Linq because it is using the power of a Join instead of for-loops and have +1 it.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there you can use Addrange method of List collection:

```
var products = db.Products.Where(q => !q.IsFeature).ToList();
foreach(Product pr in db.Products)
  if(!pr.IsFeature) pr.Features.AddRange(db.Products.Where(q => q.ParentID == pr.ID));
```

P.S. other idea is to extract features sort them, convert to array and use for loop :

```
var features = db.Products.Where(q => q.IsFeature).OrderBy(f => f.ParentID).ToArray();    
p = db.Products.First(p => p.ID == features[0].ParentID);
for(int i = 0; i < features.Length; i++ ) 
{
   if(i > 0 && features[i - 1].ParentID != features[i].ParentID)
     p = db.Products.First(p => p.ID == features[i].ParentID);
   p.Features.Add(features[i]);
}
```

Comment: I was just about to ask why you used continue; and you edited, will give this a try too, looks good thanks.

Comment: It should be ok. Haven't tested it though

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin.aspx) for this.  This is exactly what it's designed for.

```
var products = db.Products.Where(p => !p.IsFeature)
    .GroupJoin(db.Products, p => p.ID, q => q.ParentID, (p, eq) => {
        p.Features = eq.ToList();
        return p;
    })
    .ToList();
```

This code is untested, but should work.